# What are the differences between AdaDelta and RMS prop in Keras (if any)?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, keras

I have read many references which suggest that RMSprop and Adadelta are basically same, just developed independently. However, [Keras has two different classes for it](https://keras.io/api/optimizers/). Also, it allows RMS prop to have momentum but not AdaDelta. [In this link as well,](http://www.denizyuret.com/2015/03/alec-radfords-animations-for.html) RMSprop and AdaDelta have different trajectories.

I want to understand the mathematical difference between RMSprop and AdaDelta in context of Keras.

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/gradient-descent-with-rmsprop-from-scratch/

Comment: It doesnt clear my doubt